# IE tab for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser-addons, ietab

Is there any way to use **Firefox IE tab** in **ubuntu** platform. Any other way to test the page how it will shown by IE

Answer (score 9):

From what I remember, IE tab addon delegates the rendering to IE engine, so I doubt it shall ever be available for ubuntu.

There is, however, an IE for Linux that can be run in wine [here](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/).

Other solution is to use a windows virtual machine.

Side note: Microsoft recently released a handfull of VPC images with different versions of windows and ie that can be used licen-free until the end of the year: [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en). I don't know if VPC images can be run in ubuntu...

Answer (score 4):

IEtab is not actually am emulator. All it does is opens an instance of IE within Firefox, so it won't work on Mac or Linux unless you have some crazy install of IE for either.

I'd go with Alexey's suggestion. Either install a VM of Windows or RDC to a Windows box.

Good luck.

Comment: The problem with using an actual IE rendering engine is you lose all the awesome dev tools in Firefox/Chrome. I don't really need to know what a page looks like in IE. I already know it'll look horrible. What I need to know is **why** it looks horrible so I can fix it. Unfortunately, IE's dev tools have always and will always suck.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some online services such as

- http://litmusapp.com/
- http://www.browserpool.de/kc/wob/portal.jsp?lang=en
- http://browsershots.org/

Unfortuantely these are commercial services and carry subscription fees

Or you could setup a virtual machine with windows on it and try it in a native browser. Microsoft do provide XP images with different IE installations but I believe these are only for Virtual PC (which is windows only)